# How to ascend odd numbers and keep even numbers in their places

Tags: javascript

As you can see in my code, the odd numbers are ascended, but the even numbers are eliminated. I want the even numbers to stay in their places. The expected log would be `[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]`

```js
function sortArray(array) {
  let sortedNumbers = array.sort();
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sortedNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (sortedNumbers[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      newArray.push(sortedNumbers[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(sortArray([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the clearest way to do this would be to extract all the odd numbers into a separate array, sort *that* array, then insert them back into the original array:

```js
function sortArray(array) {
  const odds = array.filter(num => num % 2 === 1);
  odds.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return array.map(
    num => num % 2 === 1 ? odds.shift() : num
  );
}

console.log(sortArray([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]))
```

Note that you can't use `.sort`, because `.sort` compares lexicographically (eg `11` will come before `2`, which is wrong) - use `.sort((a, b) => a - b);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "ascended" means, but for instance if you wanted to add 0.1 to each odd number while leaving the evens as they are, you could simply add an `else` statement as follows.

Note that providing the `numericSort` function is necessary unless you want your numbers to be sorted alphabetically (which is the default for the `.sort` method.)

```js
const numericSort = (a, b) => a - b;

function sortArray(arr) {
  const
    sortedNumbers = arr.sort(numericSort),
    newArray = [];
  for(num of sortedNumbers) {
    if (num % 2 !== 0) { newArray.push(num + 0.1); }
    else { newArray.push(num); }
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(sortArray([5, 31, 20, 8, 1, 4]))
```